# UWP Display Folder Name List

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, directory, carousel

I have folders and files on the "koleksibuku" folder on carousel. I want to be when moveBtn clicked, it will display a list of names of available folders (including root folder). How do I display a list of available folders in the "koleksibuku" folder?

Code to display files and folders on gridview:

```
    loading.IsIndeterminate = true;
    StorageFolder koleksibuku = await installedLocation.CreateFolderAsync("koleksibuku", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    ObservableCollection<Book> datasource = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await koleksibuku.GetFilesAsync();
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> folders = await koleksibuku.GetFoldersAsync();
    StorageFolder thumbfolder = await installedLocation.CreateFolderAsync("thumb", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    files = await koleksibuku.GetFilesAsync();

    folders = await koleksibuku.GetFoldersAsync();
    foreach (StorageFile file in files)
                {

                    Book buku = new Book();
                    buku.Name = file.DisplayName.ToString();

                    if ((isbukudownloading(file.Name.ToString())) && (file.Name.ToString() != DownloadFileName))
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StorageFile thumbFile;
                        StorageFolder thumbFolder;
                        bool bukuada = true;
                        try
                        {
                            var folder1 = await installedLocation.GetFolderAsync("kolesibuku");
                            thumbFile = await thumbfolder.GetFileAsync(file.Name.ToString() + ".png");
                            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                            bi.SetSource(await thumbFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));
                            buku.Image = bi;
                            datasource.Add(buku);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            bukuada = false;
                        }

                        if (!bukuada)
                        {
                            loading.IsIndeterminate = true;
                            var task = Task.Run(async () => { await RenderCoverBuku(file.Name.ToString(), 0); });
                            task.Wait();
                            thumbFile = await thumbfolder.GetFileAsync(file.Name.ToString() + ".png");
                            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                            bi.SetSource(await thumbFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));
                            buku.Image = bi;
                            datasource.Add(buku);
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (StorageFolder folder in folders)
                {

                    Book buku = new Book();
                    buku.Name = folder.DisplayName.ToString();


                    BitmapImage folderImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///images/folders_png8761.png"));
                    buku.Image = folderImage;
                    datasource.Add(buku);
                }

                this.carousel.ItemsSource = datasource;
                this.carousel.SelectedItem = carousel.Items[0];
                loading.IsIndeterminate = false;
            }
private void moveBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Note:

- The name of the folder created by the user as desired user

Comment: So what's your problem? In your code, you've already got the folders and add them in `datasource`. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want when the user clicks moveBtn, it will display a list of folder names are available on a "koleksibuku" folder (including root folder). How to display a list of the folder names? Then the user can move the file to the folder selected. Note: root folder is "koleksibuku" folder.